# LineageOS 14.1 browser keeps saying "Download Unsuccessful" at 30-35%

Tags: browser, downloading, lineageos, 7.1-nougat

I recently installed LineageOS 14.1 x86 (Android 7.1.2), and have been having issues downloading with the default browser.

Every download starts working, but then fails at around ≈30-35%. I have:

- Checked connection. All downloads were happening on a reliable 4/4 bar Wi-Fi connection.
- Retried downloading. Same issue.
- Tried a different file. Still, the same issue.
- Downloaded an app from the Google Play Store (since it uses the Download Manager as well). It works just fine.
- Used an app with a built-in download manager (Google Chrome). Successfully downloads the files I was having troubles with.

Is there some way I can make the built-in browser properly download files?

Comment: IDK about Lineage but try delete data and cache of download manager (you will lose downloads, save them if needed)

Comment: From my experience the built-in browser / download manager of LOS has always been unreliable... Use alternatives whenever you can.